# Optimal transfer between to identical orbits with different RAAN

Tags: orbital-maneuver

Two orbits are given with the identical orbital elements, despite the RAAN, which differs by 90 degrees. The inclination is 80 deg, AOP is 310 deg, apogee is on 10000km, perigee on 1000km altitude.

The transfer should be done within a few days. The launcher will place 2 satellites on these orbits, the true anomalies of the satellites will differ by 180 degrees.

What is the optimal transfer trajectory to minimize the fuel consumption? How to calculate the $\Delta V$? Impulsive maneuvers are assumed.

**DEFINITIONS**

AoP is the angle from the ascending node to the periapsis.

RAAN is the angle from the reference direction to the ascending node.

**UPDATE**

I'm going to solve the Lambert problem (boundary value problem), considering 2 impulses. Is this a good idea, or there is a better way?

Comment: That will largely depend on the inclination, and the optimal maneuver will vary wildly depending on that, ranging from a pair of inclination change maneuvers, through waiting 3 months for orbital precession to do your job, up to a lunar fly-by followed by  aerobraking into the right orbit. The usual approach will be two separate launches though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's a very expensive scenario in general, and especially with your constraint of 'a few days'. And in your case it's best performed using three burns - the maneuver of orbital plane change performed near distant apoapsis.

First, let's adjust the parameters - since the perigee is at 1000km, it means you used altitudes, not radii (or your satellite would fly underground), so let's adjust that by average Earth radius (6371km).

Pe = 7371km
Ap = 16371km

a = (Ap+Pe)/2 = 11871km (let's mark this semi-major axis as a0)

Geometric proof that 2a = Ap+Pe (accounting for planet radii):
[image]

Let's have a look at what our orbits should look like:
[image]

The direct orbit change there would be a 90 degrees turn, that's original speed times $\sqrt{2}$

geometric proof: diagonal of a square:

[image]

Using Vis Viva equation

$$ v = \sqrt{GM ( {2 \over a} - {1 \over r}) } $$

we can find speed at the apogee: sqrt(G (Mass of Earth) ( 2 / 11871km - 1 / 16371km)) = [3888m/s](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sqrt(G%20(Mass%20of%20Earth)%20(%202%20%2F%2016371km%20-%201%20%2F%2011871km))). Multiplied by the aforementioned square root of 2, our delta-V is 5498m/s. That's way too expensive to do in a single launch.

The moon flyby scenario is right out due to timing constraints and inclinations that aim nowhere towards the moon.

1000x10000 is not a great eccentricity but let's see what we can work out with degrading the (actually optimal) scenario of 'plane change at infinity' to fit our timing constraints. I'll assume the 'few' days to be 10.

For the orbital period to be 10 days, semi-major axis (a1) must be [196060km](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=((%20(10%20days)%5E2%20)%20%2F%20(%204%20pi%5E2%20%2F%20(%20G%20(Mass%20of%20Earth)%20)%20)%20)%20%5E%201%2F3). Pe+Ap = 2a, so Ap = 2*196060-7371 = 384749km.

- So, first, a burn prograde at intersection of the orbital planes near periapsis to raise apoapsis. The initial speed won't be much different from the periapsis speed, so I'll approximate it with it.

Initial speed, Vis Viva with r=Pe, a=a0: [8636m/s](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sqrt(G%20(Mass%20of%20Earth)%20(%202%20%2F%207371km%20-%201%20%2F%2011871km)))
Final speed, r=Pe, a=a1: [10301m/s](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sqrt(G%20(Mass%20of%20Earth)%20(%202%20%2F%207371km%20-%201%20%2F%20196060km)))

$\Delta v_1$ = 10301 - 8636 =  1665m/s.

- At the intersection of the target orbital plane (which should happen very near the new apoapsis) perform a normal burn to adjust your orbital plane. Our apoapsis speed will be [197m/s](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sqrt(G%20(Mass%20of%20Earth)%20(%202%20%2F%20384749km%20-%201%20%2F%20196060km)))  Times $\sqrt{2}$ for the 90 degrees turn, $\Delta v_2$ = 279m/s.

The actual orbit may be a little higher or lower to make the arrival provide the correct true anomaly - make the period be the nearest (n+0.5) times the period of the satellite, instead of 10 days sharp. The change in delta-V will be quite small.

- Another 1.664km/s burn ($\Delta v_3$), retrograde, at periapsis to bring apoapsis back.

A total of 2*1664+279 = 3607m/s and that's about the least delta-V you can get it done with.

In reality, this will be done through two separate launches, because it will be cheaper than using a launcher that can bring up a transfer stage of over 3.5km/s and three reignitions besides the satellites.

The whole procedure would look kinda like this:

[image]

[image]

Comment: What value for the argument of perigee you took? Actually, I consider the AOP = 310 deg. Another question, could you explain `10.3 - 8.636 = 1.664km/s.` calculation? And why do you multiply by $\sqrt{2}$?

Comment: @Leeloo: 1. "Such that the perigee falls on intersection of the two orbital planes". It will be somewhere around +/-80 degrees from respective RAAN. The delta-V was found with two speeds obtained through Vis-Viva for r=Pe and the two respective *a* pre- and post-burn. Sqrt(2) is diagonal of a square; sum of two perpendicular (velocity) vectors, or otherwise the vector required to rotate your current velocity 90 degrees.

Comment: @Leeloo: I noticed my solution violates your requirement of 'other parameters being the same' - argument of periapsis of the two orbits differs by the same 90 degrees as RAAN. OTOH, that makes the orbits actually similar, just rotated around Earth axis. Same precession, same latitude range etc. Quite similar to Molinya constellation actually. With arg. of pe. the same but RAAN 90 degrees off you'd make them very different. One's apogee above antarctic, the other's - in equatorial zone. And they'd differ in orbital precession so much the 90 degree difference in RAAN would be quite short-lived.

Comment: You mean, difference in AOP by 90 deg is better than the same AOP? I need same AOP=310. What about a bielliptic transfer, would it give better result?

Comment: @Leeloo: "Better" is subjective, all depends on what you need these orbits for, but AOP-RAAN distance difference results in orbits that will differ in precession, so if you want a constellation, it won't be stable, varied precession breaking the relative angles.

Comment: Not even bielliptic just through edges of Hill sphere - but it would extend time by a lot. General procedure for changing orbit by *a lot*: Increase apoapsis to edge of Hill sphere, at apoapsis circularize (+plane change) into an orbit that passes through extension of your new major axis, then after arriving there (weeks!) set new inclination+periapsis as desired, then lower apoapsis by final burn at periapsis. 2 fixed-cost relatively expensive maneuvers of raising/lowering periapsis and two low-dV maneuvers at edge of the hill sphere to set up the transfer orbits.

Comment: (oh, wait... that largely depends on which definition of AoP you choose. If you choose absolute (angle to reference direction) then all my notes so far are valid. If you choose it as angle from direction of ascending node, then all is fine, if it's just the same relative to RAAN, then you're fine.)  With AoP at 310 your Pe is 50, not 80 degrees from the of reference. You'll perform your Ap. raising burn at the intersection, it will be a bit more expensive.

Comment: AoP is the angle from the ascending node to the periapsis. RAAN is the angle from the reference direction to the ascending node. As we have determined the definitions, could You please update your answer on the basis of my question? I'm confused a little

Comment: Sorry, I'm sick currently (over a month now) and this would take more focus than I have in the state I'm in... the edit will need to wait some more.

Comment: How is it going?

Comment: @Leeloo: Getting better. I need to get an hour or so with a gfx program to draw out the geometry, that will really make things clear.

Comment: As I tried this in KSP, I was actually wrong about the departure burns being nearly the same as from periapsis. To raise the apoapsis in such a way that it becomes the ascending node relative to the target orbit, you need to perform the burn a good way from periapsis and the intersection of the orbits. I'm not sure how to find that exact point, but you lose a lot of Oberth benefits. This thing is **expensive**. You just don't do such maneuvers against planets as heavy as Earth and starting with orbits so low.

Comment: Why the second burn is √2 of apoapsis speed? Isn't it √2 of apoapsis minus apoapsis speed (as we calculating the deltaV)?

Comment: @Leeloo: You're turning 90 degrees. You must cancel out the entirety of the original apoapsis speed, and then rebuild it to the exact same value in perpendicular direction. By combining the two operations you're paying $v \sqrt{2}$ instead of $2 v$, Exactly the same situation as in the earlier "direct change", the picture with perpendicular vectors - except now the apoapsis is very high and the speed is low.