# How to change RAAN with 250 m/s DV?

Tags: orbital-maneuver, orbital-elements, delta-v, python, poliastro

I'm performing a transfer between 2 orbits with different RAAN (other orbital parameters are same). The perigee altitude of the orbits is `1000km`, the apogee is `10000km`, шnclination - `64 deg`, AoP - `300 deg`.

Mission restrictions: the maximum allowed transfer time - `7 days`, the maximum allowed DV - `250 m/s`.

What is the maximum possible change in RAAN?

---

Using Lambert method (in an interval of initial and final True anomalies and Transfer times), I could rotate the plane to `3 degrees`. Is there a mistake?

**If there is another, more efficient maneuver, please, suggest.**

Comment: The two orbits with the same parameters except Right Ascension of the Ascending Node aren't going to have their apogee at the same point. The apogees are to be on the order of 3700 km apart, and unless the two orbits you describe are equatorial, they probably won't intersect at any point,  which is going to complicate the heck out of working through a low-energy transfer.

Comment: The answer probably depends on the orbits' inclination and argument of periapsis.

Comment: Isn't this just another flavor of the question you asked in Nov 2018. https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/31679/optimal-transfer-between-to-identical-orbits-with-different-raan

Comment: @CarlosN Do you think, that I'm thinking about this problem since Nov 2018? )